# How to prove that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(b)[x]$ if and only if $q(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(a)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $p(x),q(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$  be irreducible polynomials,  $p(a)=0$, for $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $q(b)=0$, for $b\in\mathbb{C}$. How can we show that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(b)[x]$ if and only if $q(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(a)[x]$?

Im using the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ and the fact that $Irr(a,\mathbb{Q})|p(x)$ and $Irr(b,\mathbb{Q})|q(x)$ to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]\leq nm$ where $n=\deg p(x)$ and $m=\deg q(x)$ but im kinda stuck on how to follow next. My guess is that i need to show that there is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not true. Let $a=3$, $b=\sqrt 3$ and $p=x(x-3)$, $q=x^2-3$.

Comment: You meant $p,q$ are irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ in which case it is true, as $p$ irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}(b)[x]\cong \Bbb{Q}[x,y]/(q(y))$ is equivalent to $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/(p(x),q(y))$ is a field.

Comment: @reuns yeah...that was a very important detail... i just edited to fit right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that $p,q$ are monic.

Since $q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ it is the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb Q$. This implies that $[\mathbb Q(b):\mathbb Q]=\deg q$.

Moreover, if $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(b)$, from $p(a)=0$ we deduce that it is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q(b)$. It follows that $[\mathbb Q(a,b):\mathbb Q(b)]=\deg p$. Thus we get $[\mathbb Q(a,b):\mathbb Q]=\deg p\deg q$.

Since $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ it is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q$. In particular, $[\mathbb Q(a):\mathbb Q]=\deg p$.

Now we get $[\mathbb Q(a,b):\mathbb Q(a)]=\deg q$. Since $q(b)=0$ we get that $q$ is the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb Q(a)$, hence $q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(a)$.

The converse is similar.

Comment: if we could show that there is an isomophism between Q(a) and Q(b) could this lead us to the wanted result ? Your solution is great ,im just curious.

Comment: Could be possible, but it's not clear to me how. We have $\mathbb Q(a)\simeq\mathbb Q[x]/(p)$ and similarly for $\mathbb Q(b)$. I don't have another idea than the one exposed by reuns in the comments.